# Steam won't give me a CD-Key

Tags: steam

I bought Dawn of War: Dark Crusade in the Steam sale so I can play as the necrons or tau in multiplayer. I don't want to install the whole expansion when I already have Soulstorm, so I downloaded a tool off the internet that will unlock the races provided I have a valid Dark Crusade CD-Key. So all I need now is the key. However, on selecting Dark Crusade in my library and clicking "CD-Key" on the right hand side, a message window pops up that simply says "Requesting Key..." and never actually gives me one. How do I fix this and get a CD-Key?

Comment: Not something we can fix. Contact steam or developers.

Comment: @ardaozkal It's interesting how certain you are about that. It's perfectly plausible that someone else had this exact problem.

Comment: I think that their license servers aren't working properly, and developers need to take care of it, Steam might help you contact them. If you have issues with your internet, Steam would give an error, but if Steam servers can't reach the license servers, it just stays on "Requesting Key...".

Comment: Off-topic, but: "so I downloaded a tool off the internet that will unlock the races provided I have a valid Dark Crusade CD-Key". Remember that executables can do anything, and unless you downloaded this tool from the developer's website, it could also simply be malware.

Comment: @Sumurai8 It was on the Relic forum and it's legit.